# Eclipse debug just running the code without step by step

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I just installed eclipse, but idk if something is wrong with the config or something.
I ran a simple test code that runs perfect, but I can't use the debug option. I installed the eclipse in my main pc and a laptop, but in both, debug work like the "run", running the code completely without allowing step option like it should, it doesn't even switch to the debug perspective or enable the options of step into step over....

Here is an img after pressing the debug

(cant post a img yet, so here is the direct link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmPJC.png

hopefully, you guys can help me

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint to tell it where to enter debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your app finishes instantly. To start debugging, you have to pause execution first, and you can't get there because this app is simple enough to get done in milliseconds. Click in the left margin somewhere near the 'top' of execution (such as: the first line of the `main` method), or double click - you want a green dot to appear (indicating a breakpoint). That'll cause a pause and then you can do all the stuff you wanna do. The debug view opens automatically *on hitting a breakpoint*, not on hitting the debug action. It's more convenient that way.